# Changing @Input() in child compoent properties prevents further updates from parent component

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I have 2 components - Parent and Child. Please see [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1mmw1p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)
Parent's template looks like below -
[image]

When 'Show Child' is clicked, isChild1Visible is set to true causing the Child component to display its template.
[image]

When you click 'Hide me' the Child component sets isVisible to false, causing it to be hidden. Now  when 'Show Child' is clicked again, the child component is not shown.

I add ngOnChanges() in the Child component to see the change detection, however I see the below
When child component is initialized:
[image]

After 'Show me' is clicked for 1st time
[image]

After 'Hide me' is clicked, the ngOnChanges() does not print anything even when 'Show me' is clicked later on.

So, why does change detection stop working after input property is update in the child component?

Comment: You have to use [Two-Way binding](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding) in order for the parent value and child value to be in sync.

Comment: try passing by an object instead of a primitive type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The issue

The first time you set `isChild1Visible`, with the one way binding it also sets the child `isVisible` to true.

From the inside, you set `isVisible` to false, so the div disappears as you have `*ngIf="isVisible"`.

However, the outer `isVisible` is still `true`!

When you hit again the outer button, there's no changes to detect as the value remains the same, so nothing is passed to the child.

See this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kq74oz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-app-child1%2Fmy-app-child1.component.html) with both booleans exposed.

### Option 1: Explicitly listen to on output

If you want to control a component from the outside, you should keep the logic outside.

A possible way is to add an `@Output` on your child that is an `EventEmitter` that emits when you want to close the child.

The parent will listen to that event and do something, like setting `isVisible` to false.

You can see it on [this updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ew4a1u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

### Option 2: Two-way binding

Similar to solution Option 1, you can create an emitter called with the same name of your input, ending with `Change` and trigger there your change.

In this case you only need to replace the binding with `[(isVisible)]="isChild1Visible"` and add `isVisibleChange` as `@Output EventEmitter<any>`.

Demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-menw3y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Yes, I did use @Output() to solve the problem, but the question is why does it not work the the way I demoed in the question.

Comment: Because the first time you set the child `isVisible` to true from the outside, then you set it to false from the child (with outside still true) and no further changes are detected.
At the end of the day, there's no changes to detect as the outside variable has never been changed once you set it `true`

I'm updating the answer.

Comment: from the parent component's perspective the input value hasn't changed, so there is no need to update it in the child component

Comment: on the second solution you forgot to emit the value : `isVisible` to the `this.isVisibleChange.emit(this.isVisible);` on the `onClick()` method. it does not without it. great solution!

Answer (score 3):

Since data isChild1Visible is being passed as an primitive type(boolean) it will "Pass by Value."

Therefore, if passing an object, array, or the like, then it is Passed by Reference, and for primitive types like numbers, it is Passed by Value.

try this without adding any extra outputs :

**MyAppChild1Component**

```
export class MyAppChild1Component implements OnInit {
  @Input() isVisible;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
  onClick() {
    this.isVisible.value = false;
  }
}

<div *ngIf="isVisible.value">
  <span>
Child
</span>
  <button (click)="onClick()">Hide me</button>
</div>
```

**AppComponent**

```
export class AppComponent {
  isChild1Visible = { value: false };
  ngOnInit() {}
  onShowChild() {
    this.isChild1Visible.value = true;
  }
}

<div>
  <p>Parent</p>
  <button (click)="onShowChild()">show Child</button>
  <app-my-app-child1 [isVisible]="isChild1Visible"></app-my-app-child1>
</div>
```

Comment: I like your answer @Hamza: Maybe this approach is not "the Best practice", but I guess that it's quite interesting to be aware of this kind of things. Thxs!

Answer (score 1):

That happens because `isChild1Visible` in app.component isn't updated when the child component sets
`isVisible`.

### First Click on `onShowChild()`

- `isChild1Visible` = true
- `isVisible` = true

### Second Click on `onClick()` in child

- `isVisible` = false;
- `isChild1Visible` = true

### Second Click on `onShowChild()`

- `isChild1Visible` = true // => No changes here
- `isVisible` = false

Since the value of `isChild1Visible` is not changed, Angular does not update anything.

In order to trigger Change Detection and keep values in sync, you need to use [Two-Way binding](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding).

```html
<app-my-app-child1 [(isVisible)]="isChild1Visible"></app-my-app-child1>
```

```
export class MyAppChild1Component implements OnInit {
  @Input() isVisible;
  @Output() isVisibleChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
  onClick() {
    this.isVisibleChange.emit(!this.isVisibleChange);
  }
}
```

[Updated Sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gzd1ly?file=src/app/my-app-child1/my-app-child1.component.ts)